# How to disable screensaver in LXDE?

Tags: arch-linux, lxde, screen-lock

I want to disable screensaver in LXDE.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several ways.

First, through GUI (Menu>Preferences>Screen Lock or Menu>Preferences>Screensavers).

Second, you can disable the screensaver daemon (through GUI Menu>Preferences>Startup Applications or Menu>Preferences>Services and untick "screensaver").

And last, be sure to turn off monitor power management (if your monitor is going blank and that's your concern).